# c# File Copy missing file extension

Tags: c#, copy

EDIT:

Rightfully down-voted as it was a terrible description, here's a better one:

I am copying SQL Server ERROR logs (not database logs), here is the code:

```
//Get Directory
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.ARC514A\MSSQL\Log");

//Get filenames in Directory
FileInfo[] fis = dir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

//Loop over each file name
foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
{
//Get files that are +/- two days of the issue
if (fi.LastWriteTime.Date > date.Date.AddDays(-2) && fi.LastWriteTime.Date < date.Date.AddDays(2))
{
File.Copy(fi.FullName, "C:\SQL_LOGS\", true);
}
}
```

The resulting error when copying the file is:

> "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10.ARC514A\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'"

It looks like this is due to the copy trying to copy the extensionless file as a folder instead, is there a way to copy files from one location to another without that file having an extension...it definitely doesn't have an extension! :)

Comment: "it throws an error"... what error? Please be *specific*.

Comment: Are you *sure* they don't have an extension?

Comment: Worked just fine for me in a quick test.

Comment: "Hide extensions for known file types". Worst Windows feature of all time.

Comment: @ErikKerber I thought IE was the worst windows feature... ;)

Comment: Also, generally paths in Windows have `\\` as the path separator.

Comment: AnnaKournikova.jpg.vbs <-- yes, worst windows feature ever.

Comment: To check the path you can press Windows+R, Copy paste your path. Press enter. A message will pop up if the file doesnt exist, obviously missing file extension.

Comment: Sorry that was the most terrible description I've ever put, see the edit please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to append the file name to the end of the directory.

```
//Loop over each file name
foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
{
    //Get files that are +/- two days of the issue
    if (fi.LastWriteTime.Date > date.Date.AddDays(-2) && fi.LastWriteTime.Date < date.Date.AddDays(2))
    {
        fi.CopyTo("C:\SQL_LOGS\" + fi.Name, overwrite: true);
    }
}
```

That should work for you.

Comment: So simple i can't believe i missed it :) didn't occur to me that the 'copy to' location would need the new file name as well! Thanks Aaron!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these are SQL Server Database log files, they are `.LDF` extension.

Try (change your path separator):

```
File.Copy(@"C:\Folder1\SQLLOG.LDF", @"C:\Folder2\SQLLOG.LDF", true);
```

Or else check the file property to find the extension and add it.

Comment: Also, these files are typically locked by the SQL Server service. Stop the service before copying the files.

Comment: @helb: He is not moving the file just copying. If source path is the original, I think it should be okay but never tried.

Comment: I can't copy the ldf files while the SQL server is running on my Win7 machine.

Comment: As per @helb's comment, you need to stop the service.

Comment: Sorry that was the most terrible description I've ever put, see the edit please :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileInfo.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.copyto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead e.g.

```
//Loop over each file name
foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
{
    //Get files that are +/- two days of the issue
    if (fi.LastWriteTime.Date > date.Date.AddDays(-2) && fi.LastWriteTime.Date < date.Date.AddDays(2))
    {
        fi.CopyTo("C:\SQL_LOGS\", overwrite: true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, although as the name suggests it seems this will move the file, i need to copy it as no changes can be made to the original file (extension/location etc).

Comment: @DanHall no worries, use `CopyTo` then :) see update.

Comment: stuck with .net 3.5 I'm afraid :(

Comment: @DanHall `CopyTo` is supported by all .NET versions.

Comment: Right you are :) Unfortunately the same error occurs with CopyTo :(

Comment: @DanHall well that's funny because clearly you *have* a reference to the file...(it's possible that CopyTo is calling the same API as `File.Copy` internally but there is nothing in the docs about that). Can you post the full exception? Including call stack?